# How to allow nil password_digest when logged in with FB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, passwords, digest

I'm 3 months into learning Rails.  Trying to add Facebook auth to a Hartl tutorial sample app clone.

I'd like to still allow users to create accounts w/o FB...  though I'm open to suggestions on that.
I want the FB login to happen instantly, without users having to enter a password.

I've been using the relevant Railscasts (#235-236, etc.) but Ryan uses devise, and I don't want to.  In fact, I find the complexity of his solution a good argument for authentication from scratch.

My current bug (after saving a user without validation) is "Password digest missing on new record" and seems to be caused by [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L63).  What are my options?

1. I'm tempted to just add a random password_digest but feel a little
   dirty about that.  Should I?
2. Should I rewrite the sign_in function?  What exactly needs to happen in it?  Maybe I don't fully understand the lifecycle of Hartl's remember_token...
3. Is there anything else I'm missing?

My code is up on [Github](https://github.com/bluemihai/turnkey.git).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **has_secure_password** module automatically adds this validation:
validates_presence_of :password_digest. And, there is no way to bypass this validation.

One solution that I can think of is to fallback to the secured password theory explained in the previous version of rails tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-two?version=3.0#sec:secure_passwords) and roll your authentication mechanism instead of using has_secure_password.